# 5.0 GHz wifi not connecting on new Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, connection

I recently got a new computer running Ubuntu(I previously owned a mac), and I've been having problems connecting to the right wifi.

My computer has no problem connecting to the 2.4 GHz, but when I open network preferences and try to select 5.0 GHz, it says that the network is 'Out of range'.

My mac is able to connect to the 5.0 GHz fine; this is the only computer in the house having problems.

Thank you for your help